# Draw wind field using wind speed and degree

Tags: gnuplot

How can I draw a wind field using the code below like this map?

```
Time  Temp Wind speed Wind direction Pressure
 202000200   10.8836    2.4982   90.5014   80.7499
 202000300    9.8425    2.6553   41.5163   90.0338
 202000400    9.5351    2.4581   40.1018   80.5542
 202000500   12.5231    4.1907  120.2293   84.4332
 202000600   17.2069    3.1405  177.5542   87.0220
 202000700   10.7297    5.5018  269.7194   81.5804
 202000800    6.0049    4.2357  309.8655   68.6385
 202000900    8.3194    2.5722   81.6993   78.4679
 202001000    8.5940    4.2101   41.0358   84.9437
 202001100    7.3084    3.8480  217.5551   70.2860
 202001200    5.5046    3.0959  158.0296   68.9129
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a gnuplot 5.2 version. You can use the plotting style `with vectors`.

Specially mentioned should be:

- `set size ratio -1` this makes x and y same scale, e.g. a 45 degree angle really appears as 45 degree angle (check `help size`). The factor `SCALE` which depends on the x and y range and the terminal size is adjusted automatically.
- To make sure the key (or legend) arrow is in the correct scale I'm not using the standard key (because I don't know what its scale relative to coordinates is) but an arrow and a label which requires some extra coding.

**Code:**

```
### plot wind directions (gnuplot 5.2)
reset session

$Data <<EOD
# Time  Temp Wind speed Wind direction Pressure
 202000200   10.8836    2.4982   90.5014   80.7499
 202000300    9.8425    2.6553   41.5163   90.0338
 202000400    9.5351    2.4581   40.1018   80.5542
 202000500   12.5231    4.1907  120.2293   84.4332
 202000600   17.2069    3.1405  177.5542   87.0220
 202000700   10.7297    5.5018  269.7194   81.5804
 202000800    6.0049    4.2357  309.8655   68.6385
 202000900    8.3194    2.5722   81.6993   78.4679
 202001000    8.5940    4.2101   41.0358   84.9437
 202001100    7.3084    3.8480  217.5551   70.2860
 202001200    5.5046    3.0959  158.0296   68.9129
EOD

set size ratio -1
set angle degrees
myTimeFmt = "%Y%j%H"

# automatic determination of "optimum" value for SCALE with given data and terminal size
plot x  # plot dummy graph otherwise GPVAL_TERM_XSIZE and GPVAL_TERM_YSIZE will be undefined
stats $Data u (timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)):($3*sin($4)) nooutput
SCALE = (STATS_max_x-STATS_min_x)/(STATS_max_y-STATS_min_y)/GPVAL_TERM_XSIZE*GPVAL_TERM_YSIZE

set title "Wind speed and direction"
set format x "%j" timedate
set xzeroaxis lt -1
set grid xtics,mxtics lt -1, lt 0
set format y ""
unset ytics

# Legend arrow in correct scale
Speed = 2.0
KeyPosX = 0.8    # relative to graph
KeyPosY = 1.08   # relative to graph
set style arrow 1 filled size graph 0.015,15 fixed lc rgb "blue"
set arrow 1 from graph KeyPosX, graph KeyPosY rto first Speed*SCALE,0 as 1
set label 1 "2 m/s" at graph KeyPosX,graph KeyPosY right offset -1,0

plot $Data u (timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)):(0):(SCALE*$3*cos($4)):(SCALE*$3*sin($4)) \
    w vectors as 1 notitle
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I have another question. In the book introducing gnupolt, `with vector` using x:y:(x+delta):(y+delta).  But I can't understand the code of this `(timecolumn(1,"%Y%j%H")):(0):(SCALE*$3*cos($4)):(SCALE*$3*sin($4))` , can you explain it ? @theozh

Comment: The syntax is `x:y:dx:dy`. So, this means the vector is drawn from `x,y` to `x+dx,y+dy`. So, in the example above `timecolumn(1,"%Y%j%H")` is `x`, `y` is `0`, `dx` is `SCALE*$3*cos($4)` and `dy` is `SCALE*$3*sin($4)`. `$3` is the windspeed, `$4` the angle. `cos($4)` gives the horizontal and `sin($4)` the vertical component each scaled with `SCALE` to see the real angle.

Comment: I understand. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

- It is not clear to me how the first column is to be interpreted (year + something?) so for the purpose of illustration I just take the last 4 digits as x coordinate.
- There are many options for defining the shape of the arrow head.  See "help set style arrow".
- The data fields for plot style `with arrows` are **x:y:length:angle**

\

```
set angle degrees
unset key
set xzeroaxis
set xrange [0:*]
set title "Wind speed and direction"

SCALE = 10.

plot $WIND using ($1 - 202000000) : (0) : ($3 * SCALE) : 4 with arrows noborder
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The first column represented the year(0000)+the day of the year（000）+hour(00).

Comment: I can't use the `arrows` in gnuplot 5.2.0, so is there another trick to achieve the goal?@ethan